# Display date/time to chat users in their own time zone

Tags: php, android, iphone, timestamp, chat

I am working on a chat module in my app. I have to display messages sent/received with a date and time. How can I ensure that each user sees an accurate sent a received time in their local time zone?

Comment: Use UTC as reference and when displaying the time to user change according to timezone ?

Comment: The accepted standard for date storage is Epoch/POSIX/Unix time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Use common Locale value/string on both ios and aos app, along with make sure how your web service API handles dates/lastUpdated flag

Comment: I followed frz3993. Thank you. I convert user's current time to UTC and store it to database and when getting from database i again convert it back to user's default time zone.